# Makefile variable not expanding to the right value

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, sh, gnu-make

I'm using sed for generating config files populated with the region attribute.
Here's the code snippet.

```
target:
    for r in $(REGIONS); do \
        echo $$r; \
        sed 's/<region>/$$r/;' pkg.yml > pkg-$$r.yml; \
    done;
```

On `make target`, the echo command works as expected, prints the apt region.
In the sed command,`<region>` is replaced by `$r` instead of the actual value of the region.

Is there anything I might be missing on?

Comment: Not sure but you might want to try putting the `sed` command in double quotes.  So `sed "s/<region>/$$r/;"` to ensure the variable is expanded.

Comment: Just to note, `$r` here is _not_ a makefile variable.  It's a shell variable.  That's why you have to escape it via `$$` and why you need double quotes here (because the shell doesn't expand shell variables inside single quotes).

Comment: Thank you @MadScientist, @G.M. It worked after adding the double-quotes.
Ah, right @MadScientist, I had missed the part about `$r` being a shell variable! 
Thank you for the clarification.